# custom domain github pages returns 404 error after using cloudflare

Tags: https, github-pages, cloudflare

So I have a custom domain name that I use, which I host my personal webpage using github pages.  Since then, I've created another repo, let's call this repo B, to which, I'd like to create github pages for.

However, because the CNAME file is with my personal website repo, it is giving me 404 errors when I try to reach repo B.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I was assuming the URL to be: example.com/repo/ However, the correct URL should be: example.com/.

To be sure, check under the github repository settings. It will tell you the URL to your repository.